# 'Including' private project file using `$CI_JOB_TOKEN`

Tags: gitlab

What I got so far is, it is possible to Authenticate with `Personal Access Token` and **include** external CI script but a cleaner approach would be to get access using `$CI_JOB_TOKEN` since it is more secure and restricted. I am looking into if it can be done this way -

```
include 'https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@raw-file-url'
```

I have tried to curl in this format in a dummy script job, but it fails to fetch the file.

Apparently, an external script can be imported using file API and $CI_JOB_TOKEN (https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/merge_requests/2346/diffs), but I am looking into if `include` feature also support this. Any suggestion on how to achieve that is appreciated.

Comment: After writing my answer, I realized that PAT probably means "Personal Access Token".

Answer (score 21):

Unfortunately, `CI_JOB_TOKEN` is very limited in scope. As of today (GitLab 11.0), you can only do two things with it:

- Authenticate with the GitLab Container (Docker) Registry
- Authenticate to trigger a multi-project pipeline (EE only)

References:

- https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/variables/
- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/

So you *cannot* use `CI_JOB_TOKEN` to download a file from another repository, neither via the raw endpoint (`/raw/<ref>/<path>`) nor the API.

Unfortunately, *deploy keys* don't help either -- they are only for SSH.

The only workable solution I've come up with is to use a separate user:

- Create a new user with `Reporter` role.
- Create a personal access token (`/profile/personal_access_tokens`) for that user with **api** and **read_repository** rights.
- Add this token as a *secret variable* in the project CI/CD settings. Call it e.g. `BUILD_USER_TOKEN`.
- Use `$BUILD_USER_TOKEN` in your CI script to access the API or project files.

This is a huge hack, and I really hope to see GitLab make `CI_JOB_TOKEN` a first-class, read-only (?) token with rights to specified resources.

Comment: My resolution so far is also the same. As it turns out there is no clean solution for this, I am awarding the declared bounty to this answer. Thank you for your valuable time.

Comment: They added `downloading dependent repositories` to the token description, they probably expanded the capability!

Comment: @Jean Unfortunately, still not work in Gitlab 11, e.g. `https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@git.company.com/project/gitlab-ci-yml/-/raw/master/some/script` redirects to login page

Comment: It works somehow for `git ls-remote https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@git.company.com/project/gitlab-ci-yml.git` but not for the plain curl. I've traced requests from git: it accesses things like `https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@git.company.com/project/gitlab-ci-yml.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack` and uses basic auth as gitlab-ci-token user. How to do that with just curl?

Comment: @Velkan Nice observation! I think you will probably need to reference the [Git HTTP Protocol](https://git-scm.com/docs/http-protocol) spec if you're going to try making requests using something other than a "real" git client.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart yes, I made it work. Although gitlab doesn't seem to allow the "dumb" version of that protocol, only the "smart" one.

Answer (score 1):

Still there is no support for the `CI_JOB_TOKEN` to have a useful API access. But they are working on it https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/3559