# GitLab: Unauthorized access to API from pipeline using CI_JOB_TOKEN

Tags: gitlab, devops, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I am trying to make a request to the api of my gitlab host to resolve a tag release information, from what i have seen on the internet is that i could be able to get this information with `curl` using the pre-defined variables in the job so i could get what i am looking for.

Right now how the curl is being executed is like this:

```
curl -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $CI_JOB_TOKEN" $CI_API_V4_URL/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/repository/tags/$CI_COMMIT_TAG
```

The response of this request is `404: Unauthorized`. I have also tried using `CI_BUILD_TOKEN` environment variable but i also get the same result.

The repository on which i am creating these jobs is not a private, just internal. So i don't know how to make this work.

In case it's necessary, here's how the job pipeline is coded:

```
fetch-tag-info:
  stage: setup
  only:
    - tags
  image: ubuntu:18.04
  before_script:
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install curl jq -y
  script:
    - "curl -H \"PRIVATE-TOKEN: $CI_JOB_TOKEN\" $CI_API_V4_URL/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/repository/tags/$CI_COMMIT_TAG -o release-notes.json"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Including' private project file using \`$CI\_JOB\_TOKEN\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50876136/including-private-project-file-using-ci-job-token)

Comment: To use `$CI_JOB_TOKEN` you need to pass it in the `JOB-TOKEN` header instead of the `PRIVATE-TOKEN`.

Answer (score -4):

You can use `CI_JOB_TOKEN` only in public project with everyone has access. See open issue in GitLab: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/issues/29566

Meanwhile, you can use the solution mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44469417/6076269, or here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51005977/6076269

Comment: I'll try the first link you've sent.

Comment: I have tried the first link and still it doesn't work.. For the other method, i have thought on that but i cannot ask my company to create a new account just for this, so what i ended up doing was to create a new access token on my behalf and store it in a private variable, not a good solution but it could make this work for now.